# How to solve this equation system with modular functions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I have the following two functions where I have two unknowns, $x$ and $y$:

\begin{align*}
A &= \frac{24}{60} (x + 60 \operatorname{mod}(10c, 26)) - 1300, \\[0.667em]
A &= \frac{26}{60} (y + 60 \operatorname{mod}(-10c, 24)) - 1300,
\end{align*}

with $c = \frac{26y - 24x}{60} $.

Assume A is given.

I want to break out $x$ and $y$ so I can have a function for them. However, I am having problems with doing this towards the modular function. I am not sure how to break out the two unknowns from the modular function. Have tried with *WolframAlpha* but with no luck.

Comment: What does $\bmod (10c,26)$ mean: the modulus is the gcd of $10c$ and $26$? Note also that the term “modular function” has a standard meaning that is *very* different from your idea of “a function in modular arithmetic”. Dickson once called homogeneous polynomials over finite fields “modular forms”, but that is not what “modular form” has meant for a very long time.

Comment: mod (10c, 26) would be 10c mod 26. Like in this link: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=10x+mod+26

Comment: Please explain the source of the equations - the bigger problem you are trying to solve, since the equations are a bit strange.

Comment: It's related to angle sensors with periods. Are they not solvable in the form they are on?

Comment: Subtracting of two equations will give equation for $c$.

Comment: Is $A$ given? If $A$ is not given, one cannot find both $x$ and $y$ as independent quantities.

Comment: Yes A is given, forgot to mention this.

Comment: If I am right possible $c$ are limited to $\frac{624n}{499}$ with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Take any of these $c$ and put into first equation to find $x$, then use $\frac{26y-24x}{60}=c$ to find $y$. There will be set of solutions $(x,y)$ corresponding to different $n$.

Comment: I think this is correct @IvanKaznacheyeu. I just tested it with a value and seemed to be correct . How did you get the values 624 and 499?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
A &= \frac{24}{60} (x + 60 \operatorname{mod}(10c, 26)) - 1300, \\
A &= \frac{26}{60} (y + 60 \operatorname{mod}(-10c, 24)) - 1300, \\
c &= \frac{26y - 24x}{60}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
60A &= 24x+1440\operatorname{mod}(10c, 26) - 78000, \\
60A &= 26y+1560\operatorname{mod}(-10c, 24)) - 78000, \\
26y &= 60c+24x
\end{align*}

$$
24x+1440\operatorname{mod}(10c, 26) - 78000 =
60c+24x+1560\operatorname{mod}(-10c, 24)) - 78000
$$

$$
24\operatorname{mod}(10c, 26) = c+26\operatorname{mod}(-10c, 24))
$$

$$a=\operatorname{mod}(-10c,24), b=\operatorname{mod}(10c, 26)\\
-10c=24k+a, 10c=26l+b, k,l\in\mathbb{Z}\\
24k+26l+a+b=0\\
a+b=-2(12k+13l)=2n, n\in \mathbb{Z}\\
b=2n-a$$

$$
24\operatorname{mod}(10c, 26) = c+26\operatorname{mod}(-10c, 24))\\
24b=c+26a\\ 48n-24a=c+26a \\ c=48n-50a$$

$$-10c=24k+a \\ 500a-480n=24k+a \\ 499a=24(k+20n) \\a=\frac{24}{499}(k+20n)$$

$$c=48n-50a \\ c=48n-\frac{1200}{499}(k+20n) \\ c=\frac{-48n-1200k}{499} \\ c=\frac{24}{499}(-2n-50k)$$

$$2n=-2(12k+13l)\\ -2n-50k=24k+26l-50k=26(l-k) \\ c=\frac{24}{499}(-2n-50k) \\ c=\frac{624}{499}(l-k) \\ c=\frac{624}{499}m,m\in\mathbb{Z}$$